# Is IntelliJ IDEA 11 capable of inserting namespace?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

Following the Spring in Action book I have reached chapter 4 where you are supposed to use the elements from the AOP namespace. However, isn't IntelliJ capable of either making the correct XML file or inserting namespace declarations for you?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [automatic import and code completion](http://www.screenr.com/IAH8) for Spring AOP namespaces.